# What is the difference between X11 keymapping and virtual console keymapping

Tags: x11, console, keyboard-layout, key-mapping

In linux we have X11 which governors keyboard layouts but sadly any changes made there don't affect the system as a whole so in a tty you are left with standard qwerty no matter what your X11 preferences are.
Recently I decided to delve into the tty so I needed to configure my layout (neo) there. In the end, I couldn't but I've got these questions to ask you:

Why do we have different files to describe X11 layouts and console layouts?
Why de we need different tools to manage those layouts?
Why no one seems interested in changing the layouts in the console? Do server administrators only use qwerty?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See about [`loadkeys(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?loadkeys+1).

Comment: I can't see how this answers any of the questions

Comment: And yet it does provide some information (besides, I posted a comment, not an answer). `loadkeys` is used to set a keyboard layout (among other things). It is independent from any graphical (X11/whatever) context. The man page provides some information about how this tool works.

Comment: My bad, it really is just a comment. I did read the man page though, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing that it would be nice if the two sets of configurations were integrated together, there are two reasons why they are different:

- they evolved separately (and no one has proposed an integrated solution which satisfies the requirements of both), and
- they have different requirements.

The Linux virtual consoles provide a terminal interface which supports POSIX termios: what you might consider low-level *character* I/O.  That was well-defined by the mid-1980s, with technology from the preceding 10 years.  The termios interface is concerned with control characters, a few video highlighting features for a single ***small*** font, etc.  It does not make a lot of assumptions about the keyboard other than that it can send characters.

X11 came near the end of the 1980s, designed to support *graphical* I/O.  It makes different assumptions than termios, e.g., graphics implies multiple fonts (and the ability to display a wide range of characters).  Also (because of the need to handle a mouse or other pointer device), it needs additional methods for handling input.

Unlike the termios interface (using a sequence of characters/bytes), X11 passes information by *events* which hold a lot of information, and events can be combined in ways not contemplated when termios was devised.  Thus, rather than encoding <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> into a character, an X11 event might pass the <kbd>control</kbd> *modifier* as one event, and a *key code* as another event.  The X11 libraries combine those events.

Though both were existing technology from the outset, X11 (even as X386) was less widely used, and basically came too late by several years to influence the design of termios.  That was all done before Linux started.  Since there was (and apparently still is) no alternative design which provides a distinct advantage, there's been no change since the mid/late-1990s.

Further reading:

- [The Linux keyboard and console HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.html)
- [Text-Terminal-HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO.html)
- [11. General Terminal Interface](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html) (POSIX)
- [The XKB Configuration Guide](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/input/XKB-Config.html)
- [Keyboard configuration in Xorg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg)